# Looking for a book/notes recommendation for some syllabus of an entrance examination

Tags: differential-geometry, book-recommendation, complex-manifolds

I'm preparing for an entrance exam. For the exam, i need to prepare the following topics: almost complex and almost contact structures, Nijendhuis tensor, contravariant and covariant almost analytic vector fields in almost complex manifolds, F-connexion, almost complex and almost contact submanifolds and hypersurfaces

> Can someone recommend me a book/lecture notes which covers the mentioned topics?

P.S: I have basic knowledge of smooth manifolds. I don't want to learn these topic very deeply, just for the sake of entrance examination which would have objective questions only.

Comment: This list of topics seems oddly specific and extremely advanced for an "entrance examination". Is "entrance examination" the actual phrase used in the naming of this exam?

Comment: Dear @DaveL.Renfro: The examination contains topics from different fields also. Moreover, there are other topics as well from manifolds. I have mentioned only those topics for which I could not find any specific reference.